# Convert ND4J INDArray to a List

Tags: java, nd4j

I'm searching how I can convert a INDArray of N lines and 1 column to a List (ArrayList or something else, doesn't matter) object.

I could cast multiple times the object, using [`myIndarray.data()`](https://nd4j.org/doc/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray.html#data--) to get a DataBuffer, then transform the DataBuffer to get an int array, then an ArrayList, but it seems a bit farfetched:

```
List myList = Arrays.asList(myArray.data().asInt());
```

Another solution would be to iterate over the array and put all the elements into the ArrayList but it doesn't seem very efficient.

Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found an answer: [NDArrayUtil.toInts](https://nd4j.org/doc/org/nd4j/linalg/util/NDArrayUtil.html#toInts-org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray-), takes `INDArray` and outputs `int[]`, but there's no documentation associated.